# Calculating an "at least" probability without summation?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions, binomial-coefficients

I know One can calculate the probability of getting at least $k$ successes in $n$ tries by summation: $$\sum_{i=k}^{n} {n \choose i}p^i(1-p)^{n-i}$$
However, is there a known way to calculate such without summation?

Comment: Yes, Brian, thank You. I will edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To my knowledge, there is no easier way for an *exact* evaluation of this formula.

However, when $n$ is large, the binomial distribution is close to a normal distribution, which can be used for an approximation.

Comment: Though one never has to sum more than $\lceil n/2\rceil$ terms, since one can take complements.

Comment: @azimut: Then, for sufficiently large _n_, I could take the integral from _k_ to _n_, yes?

Comment: @Brian M. Scott: Unfortunately, the _n_ which I am considering could run anywhere from 12 to positive infinity. :-/

Comment: @xuinkrbin: I suspected something like that; I just thought that it ought to be mentioned. You might want to look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Normal_approximation).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Normal approximation to binomial distribution is actually not that good. In fact, confidence intervals constructed using normal approximation (i.e. Wald intervals) are known to have very problematic coverage probabilities, and the exact intervals (i.e. Clopper-Pearson intervals) are not much better.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Thanks. I am thinking the cumulative distribution function could also be used to calculate the complement to which You refer, no?

Comment: @xuinkrbin: I’d expect so, though I don’t know whether that really gains you much. (This is getting pretty far outside the areas in which I’m comfortable.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing an "at least" from 12 to positive infinity, you could also do 1-p( x < 11), no?

Comment: No, the [12, +infinity) is for n; not k.